# Is the operating system changing the hashrate(when mining with cpu)?

Tags: cpu-mining, hashrate, operating-system

Currently I'm mining Monero on my raspberry pi (not very efficient I know but for educational purposes). I want to get a higher hashrate and now my question is:

**Does a CLI-based OS get you a higher hashrate than one with a graphical desktop?**

I don't think so but I'm open to other opinions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing CPU *and* GPU mining you may get a slight hashrate increase running on a non-GUI desktop. The less work your graphics card(s) / CPU(s) are doing should increase hashrate a little, but I wouldn't expect anything drastic.